# How do you clear a Spinner within an event handler

Tags: java, event-handling, javafx-2, spinner

When I press a button, I want the spinner value to reset to 0 within an event handler.

Currently I have something like this:

```
Spinner sp = new Spinner();
int shAge;
....

EventHandler submitH = new EventHandler() {  

    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        int shAge = Integer.parseInt(sp.getValue().toString());
 ....

        System.out.println(shAge);
.....
```

and logically in my mind, to clear the spinner after the value has been added to an array list, there should be something like

```
sp.clear();
```

or

```
sp.reset();
```

however I can't seem to find anything like that when looking in the documentation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Before you get downvoted, I suggest you read [ask] and improve your question accordingly.

Comment: So read the JavaFX documentation, understand what is required to get it done and write the code. You don't get things done by telling others what you want. If you're having trouble with code, post it and explain what is happening. If you get any errors, post them too.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to reset the value to `0` you can do:

```
sp.getValueFactory().setValue(0);
```

If you really want to clear the spinner you can additionally do:

```
sp.getEditor().clear();
```

But be aware that clearing the editor seems to be not fully supported. Using the increment and decrement buttons after that will throw a NullPointerException for example.